# Generate sequence with step value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following inputs:

```
double zmin;
double zmax;
int count;
int N; //Total number of element in result array
```

I want to generate a sequence of double array with zmin as first and zmax as last value. But from second value until last but one it should be steзped by (zmax-zmin)/count.

Example:

```
zmin = 1;
zmax = 10;
count = 3
```

Expected result:

```
double[] result = { 1, 4, 7, 10}
```

My try:

```
double[] result = Enumerable.Repeat(zmin, N).Select(iv => (iv +(zmax-zmin)/count)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's not an error description...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Range(double min, double max, double step)
{
    double i;
    for (i=min; i<=max; i+=step)
        yield return i;

    if (i != max+step) // added only because you want max to be returned as last item
        yield return max; 
}
```

Comment: ***sample usage*** ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an improvement on existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552870/5042926) from [Muhammad Hasan Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36464/muhammad-hasan-khan).
The solution works fine but as the decimal error accumulates over time , it produces lot of error in decimal places over time. 

First improvement on the existing solution is to get away with the accumulation of error like,

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Range(double min, double max, double step)
{
    double result = min;
    for (int i = 0; result<max; i++)
    {
        result = min + (step * i);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

This solves the problem almost but if you are even pedantic to get rid of the dirt sometimes sticking around the decimal place, you can go a step further like,

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Range(double min, double max, double step)
{
    double result = min;
    int decPlaces = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits((decimal)step)[3])[2];
    for (int i = 0; result<max; i++)
    {
        result = min + (step * i);
        yield return Math.Round(result,decPlaces);
    }
}
```

And for the way how to call the above methods,
just as an example,

```
double[] Myarray = classname.Range(0, 50, 0.01).ToArray();
```

will get you a double array with the mentioned parameters.

Comment: Another way is to take a look at Numsharp. but if this is the only purpose in your code base for numsharp then it doesnt make sense to carry around another dll or a bloated exe.

Answer (score 1):

This one is good not only for numbers, but for more complex types as date/time.

The second method allows to provide result selector - useful in some cases.

```
public static IEnumerable<TItem> Range<TItem>(
    TItem itemFrom, TItem itemTo, Func<TItem, TItem> itemSelector
) where TItem : IComparable
{
    // Call to the below method
    return Range(itemFrom, itemTo, itemSelector, o => o);
}

public static IEnumerable<TItem> Range<TItem, TResult>(
    TItem itemFrom, TItem itemTo, Func<TItem, TItem> itemSelector, Func<TItem, TResult> resultSelector
) where TItem : IComparable
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return resultSelector(itemFrom);

        if ((itemFrom = itemSelector(itemFrom)).CompareTo(itemTo) > 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Range(1, 10, o => o + 3);
```

> ```
> 1 
> 4 
> 7 
> 10
> ```

```
Range(
   DateTime.Now, 
   DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), 
   o => o.AddMonths(1), 
   o => o.ToString("MMMM"));
```

> ```
> January 
> February 
> March 
> April 
> May 
> June 
> July 
> August 
> September 
> October 
> November 
> December 
> January
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner than existing answers (as of 2020-01-22):

```cs
static IEnumerable<double> GetSteppedSequence(double from, double to, int numberOfSteps)
{
    if (numberOfSteps < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(numberOfSteps), "Number of steps must be greater than zero.");
    }

    var stepSize = (to - from) / numberOfSteps;
    return Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfSteps + 1).Select(stepIndex => from + stepIndex * stepSize);
}
```

This uses multiplication instead of repeated addition, so that rounding errors are avoided.