# Numpy.log() equivalent for C#?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, math

Is there anything equivalent to the python function numpy.log() in c#?

The function takes in array of doubles. I've been trying to find something for quite a while now..

Trying to convert the code below to C# (from python)

```
def func(money, intervals, dig=5):

log_section = [2, 10] # must be in ascending order and > 1

list = np.log(np.linspace(log_section[0], log_section[1], intervals))

s = 0
for i in range(intervals):
    s += list[i]

list = np.round(list/s*money, dig)
```

Comment: Is the "array" aspect important to you? C# generally doesn't offer arithmetic on arrays but that's an easy thing to make

Comment: @harold Quite important, trying to convert a python program to c# and that's the last thing remaining..

Comment: OK, and what is it exactly? `double[]`, `List<double>` etc

Comment: @harold double[], can be list if it makes anything easier. Added some code in the question too.

Comment: Why didn't you just write a loop? (Most of the reasons to avoid loops in NumPy don't apply to C#.)

Comment: That's some really awkward NumPy code, by the way. `log_section` is pointless, and the loop could have been replaced with a call to `numpy.sum`.

Comment: What you probably looking for is https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess maybe this?

```
using System.Linq;
...
double[] list = get_list_of_doubles();
double[] result = list.Select(d => Math.Log(d)).ToArray();
```

there is no real equivelent to numpy.linspace i dont think (but here is a rough equivelent borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552870/541038)

```
IEnumerable<double> LinSpace(double min, double max, double step)
{
    double i;
    for (i=min; i<=max; i+=step)
        yield return i;

    if (i != max+step) // added only because you want max to be returned as last item
        yield return max; 
}
```

then you can just Do

```
double[] list = LinSpace(start,stop,step).Select(d => Math.Log(d)).ToArray();
```

Comment: `linspace` takes a result element count, not a step size (because floating-point step sizes are extremely vulnerable to rounding errors, particularly rounding errors that lead to wrong output sizes).